# How to convert object in to an array in javascript in protractor

Tags: javascript, json, automation, protractor, webstorm

How to convert object into an array in javascript in protractor.

This is my code:-

```
var jsonResponse = JSON.stringify(response);
console.log('---------response is: ' + jsonResponse);
```

then I got below output:-

```
{"statusCode":200,"body":{"oBody":{"payLoad":{"sLoginId":"HDB_TW_DSA@softcell.com","iInstId":4019}}}}
```

Now, I want 200 as an output

I tried this below code for that

```
var result = Object.keys(jsonResponse).map(function(key) {
console.log([Number(key), jsonResponse[key]]);
```

But I'm getting below output

```
[ 0, '{' ]
[ 1, '"' ]
[ 2, 's' ]
[ 3, 't' ]
[ 4, 'a' ]
[ 5, 't' ]
[ 6, 'u' ]
[ 7, 's' ]
...
```

like this

but I want output as

```
[{"statusCode":200,"body":{"oBody":{"payLoad":{"sLoginId":"HDB_TW_DSA@softcell.com","iInstId":4019}}}}]
```

so, I can use 0th element of array.

Comment: `var jsonResponse = [response]`? Your output is vague.

Comment: If I read this right, Using `response.statusCode` when response is an object should give you the value 200. I assume you used JSON.parse() on the response somewhere before in code not shown? I don't get entirely how you want to wrap it all inside an array though.

Comment: @Shilly
I tried JSON.parse(response)

but i got output as [object][object]

Comment: @jenny `response` should already be an object, else `jsonResponse` would look differently. And your mapping output shows that you just map the letters of a string, confirming that `jsonResponse` is a stringified object. So `response.statusCode` should return `200`. And `[response]`, as mentioned above, should give you the output you want. Keep in mind that `response` is the javascript object, not `jsonResponse`, which is the JSON string describing a similar object.

Comment: you are working on string, convert your string to Object then perform manipulation
`var jsonResponse = JSON.parse(response);`

Answer (score 0):

As i understood your question correctly then you are trying to structure json in required format so that you can access it's data. If this is the case then my recommendation is to use node-json-transform npm that would allow you to create structure as per your need.

use **npm i node-json-transform**

[For more information refer this link](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-json-transform)